CSS class to make ordered list with circled numbers
I'm using Pandoc Markdown, which allows Makrdown to nest inside of HTML tags. I want to get ordered lists with circled numbers as follows:
<ol>
  <li style="list-style-type: '❶  '">
    First item
  </li>
  <li style="list-style-type: '❷  '">
    Second item
  </li>
</ol>

But instead I want to write them in markdown, and a CSS class to handle the rest:
<div class="circled-numbers">

1. First item
2. Second item

</div>


It's ok for this to work only up to 9 items.
This needs to work in Safari.
Accessibility is important.
Need to customize circled numbers fonts without affecting the font of the list items.

Note, for the above Markdown snippet, Pandoc will generate:
<div class="circled-numbers">
  <ol>
    <li>
      First item
    </li>
    <li>
      Second item
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>


Styling :first-child, :nth-child(x), perhaps?

Ok, maybe custom font here is a tall order, but the rest must be doable, no?

Yes, just wrapped my Markdown list in Pandoc with <div class="circled-numbers"> and it works.

I can edit CSS that my Markdown processor uses, is that what confuses you?

Your question is lacking details and is exactly the same as the one that got closed by the looks of it now - Please have a look at [ask]

You can define your own list styles:


@counter-style circled-decimal {
    system: fixed 0;
    symbols: '\24EA' '\2460' '\2461' '\2462' '\2463' '\2464' '\2465' '\2466' '\2467' '\2468' '\2469' '\246A' '\246B' '\246C' '\246D' '\246E' '\246F' '\2470' '\2471' '\2472' '\2473' '\3251' '\3252' '\3253' '\3254' '\3255' '\3256' '\3257' '\3258' '\3259' '\325a' '\325b' '\325c' '\325d' '\325e' '\325f' '\32b1' '\32b2' '\32b3' '\32b4' '\32b5' '\32b6' '\32b7' '\32b8' '\32b9' '\32ba' '\32bb' '\32bc' '\32bd' '\32be' '\32bf';
/* symbols: '⓪' '①' '②' '③' '④' '⑤' '⑥' '⑦' '⑧' '⑨' '⑩' '⑪' '⑫' '⑬' '⑭' '⑮' '⑯' '⑰' '⑱' '⑲' '⑳' '㉑' '㉒' '㉓' '㉔' '㉕' '㉖' '㉗' '㉘' '㉙' '㉚' '㉛' '㉜' '㉝' '㉞' '㉟' '㊱' '㊲' '㊳' '㊴' '㊵' '㊶' '㊷' '㊸' '㊹' '㊺' '㊻' '㊼' '㊽' '㊾' '㊿'; */
    suffix: ' ';
}

.circled-numbers ol {
   list-style: circled-decimal;
}
<div class="circled-numbers">
  <ol>
    <li>
      First item
    </li>
    <li>
      Second item
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>



https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@counter-style

Great stuff! Too bad this doesn't work in Safari (at least in my version).

Interesting. I don't have a Mac, but MDN says Safari supports it since last year.

@VladimirKeleshev Just tried it on a colleague's iPhone and it worked.

I got the following working.
.circled-numbers ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.circled-numbers ol li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 2em;
}

.circled-numbers ol li:nth-child(1)::before { content: '❶'; position: absolute; left: 0.75em; font-family: monospace; }
.circled-numbers ol li:nth-child(2)::before { content: '❷'; position: absolute; left: 0.75em; font-family: monospace; }
.circled-numbers ol li:nth-child(3)::before { content: '❸'; position: absolute; left: 0.75em; font-family: monospace; }
.circled-numbers ol li:nth-child(4)::before { content: '❹'; position: absolute; left: 0.75em; font-family: monospace; }
.circled-numbers ol li:nth-child(5)::before { content: '❺'; position: absolute; left: 0.75em; font-family: monospace; }
.circled-numbers ol li:nth-child(6)::before { content: '❻'; position: absolute; left: 0.75em; font-family: monospace; }
.circled-numbers ol li:nth-child(7)::before { content: '❼'; position: absolute; left: 0.75em; font-family: monospace; }
.circled-numbers ol li:nth-child(8)::before { content: '❽'; position: absolute; left: 0.75em; font-family: monospace; }
.circled-numbers ol li:nth-child(9)::before { content: '❾'; position: absolute; left: 0.75em; font-family: monospace; }
.circled-numbers ol li:nth-child(10)::before { content: '❿'; position: absolute; left: 0.75em; font-family: monospace; }

